# Material UI(MUI) Textfield Prop: multiline, (rows | maxRows | minRows)

Tags: material-ui, textfield

I encountered an error while using the `TextField` component.

I've checked whether the issue lies in my source code or in the MUI `TextField` component, but I was told that they couldn't provide assistance, so I'm posting here.

The problem occurs when the parent tag wrapping the `TextField` becomes hidden and then toggles back. An error message `ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications` appears, but it doesn't occur in all cases. It only happens when using certain props of the `TextField`, such as multiline, `(rows | maxRows | minRows)`.

Currently, to resolve this, I've changed the `{props.children}` approach to `{props.value === props.index && props.children}`. However, due to the previous tasks not being retained and recreated upon tab changes, I'm also considering not using MUI.

Could the issue be with the `TextField` component itself?

(Changing from hidden to `display: none` and toggling still results in the same error.)

```js
const tabList = [
  { id: "id1", label: "label1", el: <><TextField multiline rows={4} /></> },
  { id: "id2", label: "label2", el: <>test</> },
];

const CustomTabPanel = (props: TabPanelProps) => (
  <Box className="fx1 mt10" hidden={props.value !== props.index} >
    {props.value === props.index && props.children}

    {/* TextField Prop:multiline, rows -> using error : ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications */}
    {/* {props.children} */}
  </Box>
);

const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState(0);

  const selTab = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setTab(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box className="fx1 fullBox flex-column">
      <Tabs value={tab} onChange={selTab}>
        {tabList.map((row, i) => (
          <Tab key={`Tab-${i}`} label={row.label} />
        ))}
      </Tabs>
      {tabList.map((row, i) => (
        <CustomTabPanel key={`CustomTabPanel-${i}`} value={tab} index={i}>
          {row.el}
        </CustomTabPanel>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};
```